# UI credential popup is hiding behind the Services windows

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

i m sunil i have created a application that is written in visual studio in C language that i installed in my system , so it run as service .. but i want to put restriction to stop the service  by popup a UI  credential box , to stop seervice you need to fill the user name and password only then u can stop the services.. but the box is comming in back ground . so i am not able to see that popup box.i am using windows API ..CredUIPromptForCredentials().

can  u please suggest that  how to take that UI popUP in front so that user could able to pass the credentials. or any other API.

Thanks,

Sunil

Answer (score 0):

you can check in which session the popup is running from the Taskbar. If it's in session 0 (the default session for system services)then you won't be able to see it. To get the UI in front you need run the popup with current desktop's loggedon user's session.

Read this article how you can invoke the process as user http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2004/10/29/createprocessasuser.aspx

The code is in c# but you'll get the idea how it works.

Comment: Thanks u sir, But i can not run my application service in user mode because there is some more exe running regarding the service exe in Taskbar that run in system mode . so if i run my service exe in user mode it will create problem for rest of the exe related to my application..

Comment: No, you don't have run your service in user mode.. but the popup you want to show have to be in user mode so that it can be viewed in logged in user's desktop when required.

Comment: sir, actully  there is no exe running in task manager regarding UI popup. so i can not run that pop up in user mode.

Comment: one of the exe that is responsible for ui pop up is running in user mode session 1  but still popup is commingg in back of service.msc browser.

Comment: did u get any solution regarding my post ?